# Prove that the system $x\equiv a \pmod m$, $x\equiv b \pmod n$ has a solution iff $\gcd(m,n) \mid (a-b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, solution-verification

My assignment is the following:

Prove that the system 
$$x\equiv a \pmod m$$
$$x\equiv b \pmod n$$
has a solution if and only if $\gcd(m,n) \mid (a-b)$

My approach is the following:

[$\longleftarrow$] Let $x=a +r_1m = b + r_2n$, where $r_1$ y $r_2$ are whole numbers. So, $a-b=r_2n-r_1m\ (*)$. If we find  $d=$ GCD$(n,m)$, then
$$n=N\cdot d$$
$$m=M\cdot d$$
Replacing in $(*)$
$$a-b=d(r_2N-r_1M)$$

[$\longrightarrow$] If $d=\gcd(n,m)$ and $d \mid a-b$, so
$$d=\dfrac{n}{N}$$
$$d=\dfrac{m}{M}$$
and $\dfrac{n}{N}\Big |a-b$ y $\dfrac{m}{M}\Big |a-b$

How can I finish both sides of this proof?

Comment: You can use that $d=\gcd(a,b)$ is a generator of the ideal $(a,b)$, hence any linear combination of $a$ and $b$ is a multiple of $d$, and that any divisor common to $a$ and $b$ is a divisor of $d$.